# QTCaptureDevice in Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: objective-c, video, deprecated

It appears that a lot of `QTCaptureDevice` methods have been deprecated in 10.9. What is used instead now or how the heck do I initialize a `QTCaptureDevice` instance if all of the constructors are now deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the AVFoundation is where you want to go. Here's the apple guide on how to transition over from the QTKit.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2300/_index.html